# Detecting Touch ID is enabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am writing an objective-c app on iOS and i need to detect if Touch ID has been set up without showing the authentication dialog. I can of course figure it out using;

```
[myContext
evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics
localizedReason:myLocalizedReasonString reply:^(bool succes, NSError
*error)
```

but this will one the authentication dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out, turns out it was embarrassingly simple;

```
    LAContext *myContext = [[LAContext alloc] init];
    NSError *authError = nil;
    NSString *myLocalizedReasonString = @"Authenticate using your finger";

    if ([myContext canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&authError])
    {
        //if you get here, touch id has been set up
        TouchIDSetup = true;
    }
```